# Is it possible to display an CALayer without an UIView?

Tags: iphone

As far as I can tell, I *need* an UIView (or subclass of UIView) to display an CALayer on screen, right?

Then, what's the point of using CALayer for saving memory? The only point I see is when I would add several sublayers to a CALayer. Then those sublayers would not get copied 3 times for all the different tree types like presentation tree, render tree and so on. Is that right?

Answer (score 3):

You can add `CALayer`s as sublayers of another `CALayer`. Each individual layer does not have to be backed by a view, but the root layer in the hierarchy must be backed by a `UIView`.

The point is not to avoid having copies of the `CALayer`s, which are quite lightweight, but to avoid having copies of `UIViews` or, more specifically, the graphics contexts that back `UIView`s. Those take up considerably more memory.

Comment: Actually, I don't believe that UIViews take up much more memory than a CALayer does.  On the Mac, NSViews certainly are a lot heavier than CALayers, but UIViews are much more lightweight.  In my performance testing, CALayers only come out slightly ahead of UIViews when rendering, and I didn't see much of a difference in memory footprint.

Comment: Good to know. I had assumed UIViews suffer from the same limitations as NSViews.